# GrapeSwagger::Errors::UnregisteredParser: No parser registered for String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, swagger, swagger-codegen

I'm adding a Rails API using Grape where the success type should be String. When I do this the swagger_doc no longer generates as there is no parser registered for String. How do I register a String parser? Thanks to anyone that can help!

Below is the description that is being used to generate the swagger_doc

```
desc 'generate pdf',
     detail: '...',
     body_name: 'pdf',
     success: String,
     consumes: %w[application/x-www-form-urlencoded],
     failure: BaseAPI.document_errors([401, 403, 404])
```